# Opensource alternative to Anydesk

Tags: linux, open-source, remote-access, remote-desktop

I'm looking for an opensource remote desktop software like AnyDesk. Here the most relevant features I need:

- local and remote machines run Ubuntu
- built-in way to create a VPN tunnel
- reliable handling of modifiers (shift, ctrl, num-lock, etc...)
- <s>NOT cloud-based (at least, not only)</s> does not require an account or a subscription in order to connect to the devices
- clipboard handling
- unattended access

Nice to have:

- a client for Windows/Android
- drag/drop file transfer

Comment: When you say *NOT cloud-based* does that mean that you will host the system on your own server locally? Anything you want to seamlessly connect to multiple devices cannot be direct connects to the remote machines.

Comment: @YisroelTech I mean, I don't want to open an account on a third server (i.e. like Zoho Assist) in order to connect to my remote devices. It's ok to install both a client (local) and a server (remote) with a unique ID like AnyDesk does.

Comment: AnyDesk doesn't install "a server" on the host device, the server is by them online and the host and client both connect to it the server. So in order to get a seamless connection of that type and not use a 3rd party, you will need to run your own server local where all clients/hosts connect to. Otherwise, you will end up having to deal with every device, their IPs, and port forwarding.

Comment: @YisroelTech thanks for pointing it out. I'm going to edit the question.

Comment: What about [RustDesk](https://rustdesk.com/)?